# How to create a listview with custom StackLayout size Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a ListView with a Image and Labels, but the problem is, I can't resize the image with the StackLayout together. That is my XAML Code :

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
      Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
          <Image  Source="{Binding image}" />
          <Label Text="{Binding title}"
          TextColor="#f35e20" />
          <Label Text="{Binding subtitle}"
          HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
          TextColor="#503026" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I tryed to add a prop of Image `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` and the image did change but not the `StackLayout`

That is the Result :[image]

And That's what i want :
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `ListView.HasUnevenRows = true` and then after resizing the `Image` try doing `ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize()` on the instance of the `ViewCell` that got its `Image` resized?

Comment: I didn't, i iwll try!

Comment: Np. Glad it worked. Added an an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment, set `ListView.HasUnevenRows = true` so that the `ListView` does not restrict your cell's size and then you need to let the UI know that the cell's size changed by running `ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize()` on the instance of the `ViewCell` that got its `Image` resized.